# Matrix in Linear Transformations (Polynomials)

Tags: linear-algebra

Good Day!

I pretty much have a rough idea on how to deal with matrices and vectors but what boggles me are items that are in polynomials. I can basically start answering but can't seem to finish it for example:

$$L:P_2\rightarrow P_1\ is\ given\ by\ L(p(t))=p'(t)$$ having the ordered bases of $$ S=[t^2,t,1]  \ and \ G=[t,1] $$ Determine the matrix of L with respect to S to G.

From here I know that I should set $$p(t)=at^2+bt+c$$ and then getting its derivative $$p'(t)=2at+b$$ then I know that I should substitute S to L(t): $$ L(t^2)=2t$$$$L(t)=1$$ $$L(1)=0$$

So from this point I am quite lost I have no idea on how I should proceed even the substituting part seems hazy to me I understood that you differentiate the value itself (the one in S) but I don't understand why just I don't substitute the value to p'(t). The book I have did not really explain why that happened. Any tips or hints on how I could go about this I am not really looking for the answer, I am just looking for the process on how I could solve this. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you mean $L(p(t))$ instead of $L(t)$?

Comment: @RedPhoenix Now that you have mentioned that the haziness cleared immediately on why we differentiate the values in S

Comment: so yo meant there is no problem, right?

Comment: @RedPhoenix I don't mean to interrupt your night/day but I kinda need help on how I should proceed what would be my next step?

Comment: any element in domain is a linear combination of $t^2,t$ and $1$. Show that the image is also a linear combination of images of $t^2,t,1$ which are $2t,1,0$. The domain is span of $t^2,t,1$ and the image is span of $t,1$. The image of any element in domain is determined by the images of $t^2,t$ and $1$.